# Unable to modify function parameters within function body

Tags: swift, immutability, downcast

I have a method definition in a swift project:

```
class func fireGetRequest(urlString: String!, username: String?, password: String?, completionBlock:(NSDictionary)->Void) {
    //check if user passed nil userName
    if username == nil || password == nil {
        // retrieve userName, password from keychain
        // here we have OR check since we have single value from pair it is of no use and can be considered as corrupted data
        // so it is better to retrieve stable data from keychain for further processing
        let (dataDict, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(kKeychainUserAccountName)

        // no error found :)
        // use data retrieved
        if error == nil {
            username = dataDict[kKeychainUserNameKey]
            password = dataDict[kKeychainUserPwdKey]
        }
    }

    // do something with username, password
}
```

Here I am doing following things:

1. Checking if any of username, password is nil or not
2. If any of those is nil then trying to set respective values from a dictionary

Problem is - I am clueless on resolving below errors:

[image]

Similar method in objective-c works perfectly:

```
+ (void)fireGetRequestWithUrlString:(NSString *)urlString userName:(NSString *)username userPwd:(NSString *)password{
    NSDictionary *dataDict = @{kKeychainUserNameKey: @"Some user name", kKeychainUserPwdKey: @"Some password"};

    if (!username || !password) {
        username = dataDict[kKeychainUserNameKey];
        password = dataDict[kKeychainUserPwdKey];
    }

    // do something with username, password
}
```

Any ideas?

**Update 1:**

As suggested in answers I declared function parameters- username and password as var but then I started getting these compilation errors:

[image]

To resolve this I did type casting but again another error:

[image]

On force downcasting, below error:

[image]

Still clueless :(

**Finally solved :)**

```
if let dataDictionary = dataDict {
                    username = dataDictionary[kKeychainUserNameKey] as! String?
                    password = dataDictionary[kKeychainUserPwdKey] as! String?
                }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Function parameters are constants by default.

Define the mutable parameters explicitly as `var`

**Swift 2**

```
class func fireGetRequest(urlString: String!, var username: String?, var password: String?, completionBlock:(NSDictionary)->Void)
```

**Swift 3**

```
class func fireGetRequest(urlString: String!, username: String?, password: String?, completionBlock:(NSDictionary)->Void){
   var username = username
   var password = password
   //Other code goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried as suggested but was again caught in compilation error, please see my updated question.

Comment: as both `username` and `password` are optionals, just downcast optional to String `username = dataDict[kKeychainUserNameKey] as? String`. If the dictionary contains the appropriate key, you get an optional string otherwise `nil`

Comment: thanks for guiding me in correct direction, I was finally able to resolve the sequence of compilation errors, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: with you "solved" syntax you still get a runtime error if the dictionary doesn't contain one of the keys and `as! String?` is a confusing syntax. Either cast optional `as?` or forced `as!`, but omit the question mark after the type, in both cases on success the resulting type is the type of the target variable

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the username and password as `var`. The default is `let`.

```
class func fireGetRequest(urlString: String!, var username: String?, var password: String?, completionBlock:(NSDictionary)->Void) {
    // ...
}
```

See also: [The Swift Programming Language: Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)

> #### Constant and Variable Parameters
>
> Function parameters are constants by default. Trying to change the value of a function parameter from within the body of that function results in a compile-time error. This means that you can’t change the value of a parameter by mistake.
>
> However, sometimes it is useful for a function to have a variable copy of a parameter’s value to work with. You can avoid defining a new variable yourself within the function by specifying one or more parameters as *variable parameters* instead. Variable parameters are available as variables rather than as constants, and give a new modifiable copy of the parameter’s value for your function to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried as suggested but was again caught in compilation error, please see my updated question.